# Recommendations for organizing deep nested resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Could you please recommend best way to organize deeply nested resource in Rails? My models go as deep as 8 levels. I am pretty new to Rails, so not sure how bad it is to do nesting this deep.

Comment: Reconsider the need for nesting in your application, perhaps provide an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: there is a rule of thumb not to nest resources more than two levels deep...

Comment: Devin, I am doing simple object composition, for example Account has Customers, Customers has Orders, Order has Products which has Bill Of Material ans so on. As I am new to Rails, I thought the only way to expose these entities in restful way is resource nesting in single graph. What are the alternatives I have?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead with the [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem. It has great documentation and easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, I will checkout ancestry tonight, I have also added further clarification above.